# Edits and changes are not reflected robots.txt file Magento

Tags: magento, caching, edit, robots.txt, no-response

> google is not crawling some of my site urls
>
> for that i want to made some changes in the robots,txt file
>
> . but when i go to the magento root folder and i try to edit the
>   robot.txt file

, and when i reload that file on the browser it is not showing the changes i made in the files.
the file permission is set to 777 and the cache is clear

> I even rename the file but it still loads on browser.

Please suggest me what can be the issue.

thanks in advance.

Comment: checked in other system or other browser...

Comment: or,your instance have cache problem...

Comment: i have already tried in another browser but still same